# what is the best way to write multidimensional arrays in PHP?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, associative-array

OK here is the issue I have more than one product which needs a note displayed.  What would be the best way to echo the note to more than one product without writing the whole of the below code out for each product?

```
<?php if ($data['header']['group_code'] == 'R088X') { ?>

<li><span>Printers:</span> Wipe the allocated print area before print application with methylated spirit.</li>

<?php } ?>
```

I have tried the following put it doesn't work...

```
<?php 
$data = array((['header']['group_code'] == 'R088X', 'R129X'));

if (in_array(['header']['category'] == 'R088X', $data)) { ?>

                                        <li><span>Printers:</span> Wipe the allocated print area before print application with methylated spirit.</li>
<?php } ?>
```

Any suggestions would be grateful:)

Comment: Learning the basic syntax of PHP arrays would be a good start: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$data = array (
    'header' => array (
        'group_code' => array (
            'R088X',
            'R129X'
        )
     )
);
```

PHP is not the nicest programming language to write in when it comes to arrays!

If you are running PHP 5.4, however, you can write this:

```
$data = [
    'header' => [
        'group_code' => [
            'R088X',
            'R129X'
        ]
     ]
];
```

Comment: Hi Darkzaelus thanks for your answer However I can't get the note to go with JUST the products in my array, it's now showing on ALL products.  Do I still need the 'if'   <?php         $data = array ('header' => array ('group_code' => array ( 'R088X', 'R129X'                                                                )
  ));
 { ?>
<li><span>Printers:</span> Wipe the allocated print area before print application with methylated spirit.</li>
<?php } ?>

Comment: I think what you need is: `if (in_array('R088X', $data['header']['group_code'])): { ?> ...`, should do the trick! But yes, you need the `if`. If this answer was helpful for you, may you check the green tick under the vote count for this answer? D

Comment: Thanks but still showing on all pages:( This is what I have  $data = array (
                                          'header' => array (
                                          'group_code' => array ( 'R088X', 'R129X'                                                                )
                                                                 )
                                                                );
  if (in_array('R088X', 'R129X' $data['header']['group_code']));   { ?>

Comment: First, remove the semicolon before the `{`, secondly write: `if (in_array(array ('R088X', 'R129X'), $data['header']['group_code'])`, note that I've wrapped the two group codes in another `array()` expression. Also, can you write your code in your comments in grave accents (left of the `1` key), they highlight it and make it easier to read :) Reading material: http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Comment: Darkzalelus many thanks for your help. code below now doesn't show note on ANY product page:/ `<?php 
           $data = array (
                                          'header' => array (
                                          'group_code' => array ( 'R088', 'R129X'                                                                 ))
                                                                );
        
        if (in_array(array ('R088X', 'R129X'), $data['header']['group_code']))        { ?>`

Comment: one thing that's probably not helping is the fact that in your `$data` declaration, you're using `R088`, rather than `R088X`. I've also looked at the documentation for `in_array()` and realised I misunderstood it :) if you back to the code in my second comment, that will work. However, you need to introduce something unique for each product page. I guess that you need to substitute the `'R088X'` with the group code for that product, from the database or wherever you are getting it from.

Comment: Also your definition of $data is slightly incorrect, you specify `'R088'` rather than `'R088X'`

Comment: Hi thanks for all your help! Yes you're correct R088 should be R088X. I shall try again with your suggestions from your second comment:)

Comment: `<?php 
   $data = array (
                                          'header' => array (
                                          'group_code' => array ( 
            'R088X',         'R129X'  )               
                                                        )
                                               );
  if (in_array('R088X', 'R129X', $data['header']['group_code'])):  endif; 
           {?>                                <li><span>Printers:</span> note</li>
                                        <?php }?>`  This showing the note on ALL pages, like the 'if' is being ignoed:/

Comment: Well, a couple of problems here. Firstly, `in_array()` (the version you want to use) only takes two arguments, the string you want to check for and the array you want to check against. Secondly, you've got the `endif;` straight after the `if:`. You see the `{`? Stuff inside of the `{` and `}` are shown depending on the value of the stuff inside `if(...)`. You need to put the `{` straight after the closing bracket of the `if()`, e.g. `if(...) { ?> ... <?php }?>`

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @Darkzaelus answer, in PHP 5.4 you can do:

```
$data = [ 'header' => [ 'group_code' => [ 'R088X', 'R129X' ] ] ];
```

Comment: The one thing I'm not so keen about with Stackoverflow is it is so fast paced! I didn't know that you had written this answer when I had edited mine!